# Is there a way to promote a managed package from the CLI?

Tags: managed-package, package, beta-managed-package, cli, managed-extension

If I created a managed packaged (Beta) in a developer environment is there a way to promote this package to an Alpha?

Use Case:

1. We are experimenting with Package Extensions. However, if order to create and deploy managed package extensions from the base package, the base package needs to be an Alpha Version.
2. We have promoted unlocked packages from the CLI before, is there a similar mechnansim for Managed Packages or is the only way for promotion is getting this package into the AppExchange?

I need to validate this notion with some peer review (IE you guys :)) since I dont think this is possible but some other stakeholders think that we can do this using the same methodology as an unlocked package. Any insight would be great!

[image]

Comment: 1GP or 2GP packages?

Answer (score 3):

First generation packages can't be promoted. You would use the `package1 version create` to create a new Released version. You must be using a second generation package in order to use `package version promote` function. Note that the warning bar has nothing to do with "promotion". If your package has passed Security Review, this banner will be removed from the install page. You do not need to be in "published" status on the AppExchange to remove the banner.

Comment: Thanks as always SFDCFOX!  I missed the released setting on the UI so I thought I had to do this from the Command Line (Face Palm)